# Checkout SVN svn+ssh repo with subversive in Eclipse Helios

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive, javahl

from my computer (Mac OS X Leopard) through shell I can check out without problem a remote SVN repo. I already established ssh keys and all that stuff. Now I installed eclipse helios on mac and the subversive pluging. I find no way yo make it work with the svn+ssh repo, could you point me to some good tutorial? MY google caan not find anything useful today

PS: This is the error I get:

```
    SVN: '0x00400006: Validate Repository Location' operation finished with error: Selected SVN connector library is not available or cannot be loaded.
If you selected native JavaHL connector, please check if binaries are available or install and select pure Java Subversion connector from the plug-in connectors update site.
If connectors already installed then you can change the selected one at: Window->Preferences->Team->SVN->SVN Connector.
Selected SVN connector library is not available or cannot be loaded.
If you selected native JavaHL connector, please check if binaries are available or install and select pure Java Subversion connector from the plug-in connectors update site.
If connectors already installed then you can change the selected one at: Window->Preferences->Team->SVN->SVN Connector.
```

PS2: It seems there is a problem with the already JAVA connector, how oculd I install a new one like the SVN kit one?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

- Go to `Help > Install New Software...`
- Paste in the URL
  for juno: http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/3.0/juno-site/
  for kepler: http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/3.0/kepler-site/
- Select the connector you wish to install (I usually go with `SVNKit`). You need to select both the wanted connector and the generic "`Subversive SVN Connectors`" item.
- Click `Finish`

You should be able to use your repository now, but if not :

- Go to `Window > Preferences`
- Browse to the `Team > SVN` item
- In the `SVN Connector` tab, make sure that SVNKit is selected as the active one.

Comment: DO you know of a way to update the SVN Kit to a newer version that's not showing up when you first install Subversive?

Comment: Appart from what I can find on google, no real idea. You should be able to update it by using the update site http://www.svnkit.com/ (simply follow the first 4 steps I gave in the answer above with that URL instead of the on I gave in step 2).

Comment: I already had Subclipse installed and working, but the second half of your answer was the key to solving the problem for me... Thanks!

Comment: @pandit which URL? the one I gave in my answer (for subversive itself), or the one I put in my above comment (for svnkit)? The former still works from here, for the latter you need to use http://eclipse.svnkit.com/1.7.x/.

Answer (score 16):

For eclipse juno you  have to replace word "updated" to "juno" in the plugin link.

So working link for eclipse juno is:

http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/3.0/juno-site/

Answer (score 13):

for eclipse kepler you can use this

http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/3.0/kepler-site/

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue in Helios using **subclipse**.

Go to Help> Eclipse Marketplace
search for **subclipse** and install

[image: subclipse]

Answer (score 1):

Go to:

```
Help -> Eclipse Marketplace -> Subclipse
```

worked for me in `Eclipse Luna`

Answer (score 1):

### Last version (`July 2019`):

http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/6.0/builds/

---

### See '*How to*' picture below:

[image: SCREENSHOT HERE: *Explaining how to install Polarion Subversive software*]

---

### See '*How to*' version without pictures below:

**In your internet browser,**

1. Go to  `http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/6.0/builds/`
2. Download `Subversive-connectors-allplatforms-6.0.4.I20161211-1700.zip`

**In eclipse,**

3. open the menu `'Help'`
4. choose `'Install new software'`
5. click on `'Add'` in the `'Install'` popup
6. click on `'Archive'` on `'Add Repository'` popup
7. choose the zip downloaded previously
8. click on `'Open'`
9. tick all the checkboxes in the `'Install'` popup
10. click `'Next'`
11. wait eclipse calculations to process
12. click `'Next'`
13. click the radio button `'I accept the terms of license agreement'`
14. click `'Finish'`
15. click `'Install anyway'` in the `'Security warning'` popup
16. wait eclipse to process
17. click `'Restart now'` in `'Software Updates'` popup
18. wait eclipse to restart

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23602653)

Comment: Thanks. The screenshot explains how to do it.

Comment: Just want to note that some people can't see images. My work network blocks imgur.com, so even if you embedded it in the post, I still can't see it. Right now your answer just reads as an updated duplicate of some of the other answers here with two links to outside resources. You should try to clarify what it is that your answer adds to the existing answers.

Comment: I updated the answer with textual explanation.
Thanks again Mihai Chelaru.