# getting error while connecting with repo

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn, javahl

While connecting to `SVN` through `Eclipse Juno`, I get the below error but if I connect through previous version of `Eclipse` previous to `Juno`then it connects easily. The error I am getting is shown below, please advise how to overcome fro this as I want to use `Juno` as `Eclipse` editor.

```
SVN: '0x00400006: Validate Repository Location' operation finished with error: Selected SVN connector library is not available or cannot be loaded.
If you selected native JavaHL connector, please check if binaries are available or install and select pure Java Subversion connector from the plug-in connectors update site.
If connectors already installed then you can change the selected one at: Window->Preferences->Team->SVN->SVN Connector.
Selected SVN connector library is not available or cannot be loaded.
If you selected native JavaHL connector, please check if binaries are available or install and select pure Java Subversion connector from the plug-in connectors update site.
If connectors already installed then you can change the selected one at: Window->Preferences->Team->SVN->SVN Connector.
```

Comment: well got the solution at the following url ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136898/checkout-svn-svnssh-repo-with-subversive-in-eclipse-helios

Comment: for spring jms also I get this url ..http://www.hartmannsoftware.com/JMS_Tutorial.pdf

Comment: Check out this URL once...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17932037/eclipse-error-when-using-subversive/18820806#18820806