# Eclipse error when using Subversive

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, subversive

I am following the [instructions here](http://www.headfirstandroid.com/p/guide-importing-projects-from-google.html) to get the repositories for `Head First Android`. I have installed `Subversive` and followed from the steps to get the actual repos.

However, I get an error as under:

```
SVN: '0x00400006: Validate Repository Location' operation finished with error: Selected SVN connector library is not available or cannot be loaded.
If you selected native JavaHL connector, please check if binaries are available or install and select pure Java Subversion connector from the plug-in connectors update site.
If connectors already installed then you can change the selected one at: Window->Preferences->Team->SVN->SVN Connector.
Selected SVN connector library is not available or cannot be loaded.
If you selected native JavaHL connector, please check if binaries are available or install and select pure Java Subversion connector from the plug-in connectors update site.
If connectors already installed then you can change the selected one at: Window->Preferences->Team->SVN->SVN Connector.
```

I read the error message and :

I tried `If connectors already installed...` No, they are not.

`If you selected native JavaHL connector` No, I did not.

`If connectors already installed then you can change the selected one...` Nothing installed so can not change.

**Can someone tell me how to get this working??**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That means you didn't installed any connectors. so, to install the connectors, follow the steps below.

In Eclipse, goto help--> Install New Software

in,install window, enter the below url in work with text field http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/2.0/update-site/

then in the below box you'll get list of connectors, select those and click next...

EDIT:

The link is an update site for Eclipse 2.0 which is quite old. For Eclipse Luna, [this](http://www.polarion.com/products/svn/subversive/download.php?utm_source=eclipse.org&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=subversive) page gives the instructions. Copy this [link](http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/4.0/luna-site/) for the update site if you know the procedure.

Comment: The links for installing connectors are outdated.  The option that seems to work for Eclipse Mars 2 (ver. 4.5.2) or latest Eclipse Photon (ver. 4.8.0) is the one described by @Ioannis Mitrolios. See below.

Answer (score 20):

What get me out of this error box, go to

1. window
2. preferences
3. team
4. svn(just clicked)
5. SVN connector
6. get Connectors and Installed connectors.

Comment: Thank you @Ioannis Mitrolios. The solution you described worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

If somebody reading in 2023:

Follow instructions on [Eclpse web page - Phase 2](https://www.eclipse.org/subversive/installation-instructions.php)

In Eclipse:

1. Help -> Install New Software
2. Enter
   `https://osspit.org/eclipse/subversive-connectors/`
3. Click `Add...`
4. Select all options
5. Confirm the certificate (or its lacking)
6. Restart Eclipse