# Not able to create SVN repository in my eclipse Indigo

Tags: svn

I am trying to make a SVN repository. I downloaded subversion and when I am trying to create a SVN than I am getting error -

```
SVN: '0x00400006: Validate Repository Location' operation finished with error: Selected SVN connector library is not available or cannot be loaded.
If you selected native JavaHL connector, please check if binaries are available or install and select pure Java Subversion connector from the plug-in connectors update site.
If connectors already installed then you can change the selected one at: Window->Preferences->Team->SVN->SVN Connector.
Selected SVN connector library is not available or cannot be loaded.
If you selected native JavaHL connector, please check if binaries are available or install and select pure Java Subversion connector from the plug-in connectors update site.
If connectors already installed then you can change the selected one at: Window->Preferences->Team->SVN->SVN Connector.
```

I am using Eclipse  Indigo and my system is of 64-bit.
I got asolution on [Checkout SVN svn+ssh repo with subversive in Eclipse Helios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136898/checkout-svn-svnssh-repo-with-subversive-in-eclipse-helios?s=9bcb78fc-5ac7-4394-a919-82abdc59bd84) but Answer is not working for me any clue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to use JavaHL? If so, you'll also need the Subversion API libraries which aren't necessarily included in JavaHL.

Otherwise, you can use SVNKit which doesn't require the Subversion API libraries.

This can be selected via the Windows->Preferences dialog box. Go to Team->SVN and look under SVN interface section and select SVNKit.

Comment: I am not getting any option like SVNKit at that place.

Comment: @pandit Go to the Help menu and install [CollabNet Desktop - Eclipse Edition](http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/desktops/installing_cdee.html) This should give you the option of installing SVNKit. (As well as Subversive). One of the problems is that SVNKIt's [Open Source license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVNKit#Licensing) is a bit wanky, and Subclipse might not have given you the choice over JavaHL. See [the SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.developer.usingapi.otherlangs) about SVNKIt vs JavaHL.

Comment: @pandit - One more thing: You can use SVNKit with either Subclipse or Subversive. You don't have to use Subversive as your Eclipse SVN client if you rather use Subversive.

Comment: @pandit - I just looked at the Subversive webpage: _JavaHL and SVNKit EPL-incompatible SVN Connectors are marked as “exempt pre-req” and “works with” dependencies (correspondingly) and are distributed from polarion.com_. That might be the issue: Subversive might not have installed either plugin.

Comment: I got my solution, binary files was missing